# Raspbian script - launch gui as root and open the pdf file for 60 seconds

Tags: bash, pdf, raspberry-pi, raspbian, sudo

I'm working with a Raspberry Pi B+ with Raspbian installed. I would like to write a script (in `/etc/rc.local`) which:

1. Auto launch GUI as root (it's done)
2. In the start opens a specific PDF file for 60 seconds, then opens next PDF file and goes again.

I've tried writing anything, but I don't have an idea what to do.

```
#Auto launch gui as root
sudo startx

#Open pdf file on full screen
while true;
do
    xpdf -fullscreen /home/share/1.pdf
    echo "0"
    sleep 60
    while true;
    do
        DESTDIR = /home/share
        xpdf -fullscreen $DESTDIR/*.pdf
        sleep 60
    done
done
exit 0
```

Has someone an idea or can someone please tell me what I should do? Any help pointers?

Answer (score 0):

1) Loop over the wildcard.

```
for FILE in /home/share/*.pdf
do
    ...
done
```

2) The call to `xpdf` will block until closed by the user; you need to background it.

```
xpdf -fullscreen $FILE &
```

3) Get the PID of the process you just did send to the background.

```
XPDFPID=$!
```

4) Terminate the process after 60 seconds.

```
sleep 60
kill ${XPDFPID}
```

5) Be aware that this is all kinds of ugly, especially when run as root. For one, the PID that `xpdf` got a minute ago might now be taken by a *different* process... which you will then go on and kill regardless. *Such things should never be run as root.* Create a dedicated "technical user" to run this script, so that the only processes it can kill are its own.

6) This all is untested, back-of-the-napkin to get you moving again.

Comment: okey let me think:

code:

#Make autostart
startx

#Open pdf file on fullscreen

for FILE in /home/share/*.pdf
do
xpdf -fullscreen $FILE & XPDFPID=$!
sleep 60
kill ${XPDFPID}
done

exit 0

Would it work?

Comment: @Prochu1991: Put `echo`s in there and check the commands you're getting from the loop. Then execute one of those commands (or series of commands) to check if they give you the desired behaviour.